# RX Java 2 contract on sequential processing

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-java2

TL; DR - is it guaranteed that by default, only one thread is ever used in any given time when observing events emitted by Observable?

It seems to me that RxJava2 is generally sequential unless expressed otherwise via things like parallel(). Even with observeOn/subscribeOn, I see that there are e.g. never two threads running simultaneously for doOnNext():

```
AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();

PublishSubject<Integer> testSubject = PublishSubject.create();

testSubject
.observeOn(Schedulers.io())
.doOnNext(val -> {
  if(counter.incrementAndGet() > 1)
    System.out.println("Whoa!!!!"); // <- never happens

  Thread.sleep(20);

  counter.decrementAndGet();
})
.subscribe();

for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
  Thread.sleep(10);
  testSubject.onNext(i);
}
```

No matter how I change this example - unless I go hardcore with .toFlowable(...).parallel().runOn(...), I don't see doOnNext running on different threads simultaneously.

I'd like to rely on this feature so I can ignore synchronisation issues in my operators, however I never saw it explicitly specified in the documentation for either RxJava2, RxJava1 or even just RX in general. Maybe I just missed it, could anyone pls point me to where this part of the contract is described?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://reactivex.io/documentation/contract.html

> Observables must issue notifications to observers serially (not in
>   parallel). They may issue these notifications from different threads,
>   but there must be a formal happens-before relationship between the
>   notifications.

In your example you are not breaks this observable contract. But if you implement `Observable` wrong, two threads will run simultaneously:

```
AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();

    Observable.create(emitter -> {
        new Thread(() -> {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1);
                    emitter.onNext(i);
                } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
            Thread.sleep(1);
            emitter.onNext(i);

        }
    }).doOnNext(integer -> {
        if (counter.incrementAndGet() > 1)
            System.out.println("Whoaa!");
        counter.decrementAndGet();
        Thread.sleep(1);

    }).subscribe();
```

Seems you can fix this behavior with `observeOn` https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/5550#issuecomment-325114185

Comment: Thanks @zella ! It seems like what I need.

Answer (score 0):

1. remove `Thread.sleep(10);` to bombard the subject
2. Sleep for longer in the worker to simulate longer running task.
3. Add `Thread.sleep(10000)` under the loop, so that your **main** thread waits for the background threads to do their work
4. Change your thread pool `.subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())` if you want to force each worker to run on new thread.

Comment: I think the question was "is it guaranteed that by default, only one thread is ever used", for which this isn't an answer.

Comment: Thanks @eis - yes that's pretty much the question. I added it to the original post, thanks for making it more clear.